# Powershell - Effectively use single and double click mouse event on listview?

Tags: c#, powershell, winforms, listview

I have a listview that contains large icons. I want to be able to use the single and double click event actions but at least try to have the single click not interfere with the double click.  I found this piece of code but am having trouble trying to convert it to Powershell:

```
bool doubleClicked = false;

private async void listView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime);

    if (doubleClicked) {
        Console.WriteLine("ListView Click - Already Double-Clicked");
        doubleClicked = false;
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine("ListView Click");
    }
}

private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    doubleClicked = true;
    Console.WriteLine("ListView Double-Click");
}
```

Is the below line just a simple 'Start-Sleep' or is it something else that waits until the double click mouse event finishes?

```
await Task.Delay(SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime);
```

Thanks!

Comment: That gives the control back to the calling thread and promises to resume there when the time specified has elapsed

Comment: So is it just a simple delay, essentially?

Comment: Not that simple, but you can consider it a *delay* (as the name implies - creates an awaitable Task that resumes there after the specified time)

Comment: Do you know a Powershell equivalent I could use?

Comment: You can run C# code in PowerShell. Async / Await is not supported directly

Comment: Do you know of another way that might work to use a single and double click, effectively?

Comment: Calling `Task.Delay()` is not that different from starting a Timer (`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, in this case). Still act as a callback

Comment: I'll have to go back and see how the timer would work. I found it somewhere but lost it, again!